# Azure VPN Configuration - Connect to existing VPN

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network, checkpoint

I'm trying to connect my Azure Web App to an Existing VPN.

To connect to this VPN I must give to the admin some configurations, but I'm not sure of HOW can I provide them from Windows Azure.

As far as I have understand is all about creating the Virtual Network and the "connect it".

Like:

- Create Virtual Network
- Create Public Gateway
- Create Local Gateway
- Connect something somehow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal

In my specific case, for the configuration, are required a lot of parameter that I don't know how / where to find:

- VPN Endpoint IP
- IKE (Encryption type, Authentication Method, Diffie-Hellman Group, Sec Lifetime, Preshared secret)
- IPSEC (Perfect Forward Secrecy)
- Network profile

In the docs there is a link to Check Point NGX and Microtik so I check out this tutorial:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netgeeks/2017/07/11/creating-a-site-to-site-vpn-ipsec-ikev2-with-azure-and-mikrotik-routeros/

But how can I get this parameter to perform the connection? Do I need to install extra software on my WebApp? How can I include my web app in the VPN?

And, is there any simplify way for Web App that does not include creating the whole infrastructure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to reach on-prem from the Web App? If it's just one service (e.g. one API/database), take a look at Hybrid Connections first - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Comment: Could you please give more details? My understanding is that you have Azure Web App and you need to connect to an on-premises network via VPN?

Comment: @ThuanNg yes, you should download HCM to your local machine, then connect it via HCM,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EvilSnobu said, you can use Hybrid connections to connect your Azure APP service and your on-premises.

Hybrid Connections can be used to access application resources in other networks.

> My understanding is that you have Azure Web App and you need to
>   connect to an on-premises network via VPN?

You are right, the Hybrid connection feature requires a relay **agent** in the network that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint.

You should **download** and **install** Hybrid connection manager (HCM) on your local machine and use it to connect to that app service.

Comment: The question was made by Ziba. I just asked to clarify. But thank for your helpful info.

Comment: @ThuanNg fine, if you need more help, please let me know:)